# How to say how much time ago in text using a date field and SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In the JavaScript library `moment.js`, we can insert a date, and get the relative date difference from now in long English. For example, if I were to input yesterday's physical date, I would receive the response 'yesterday' (similar time-stamping in Facebook's news line).

Has anyone seen any examples of this feature set in SQL Server or comparative technology? I need to understand the logic to convert dates to the English representation similar to moment.js so I can begin constructing the query.

Thank you.

Comment: thought I did.  Trying again.  how's that.

Comment: Not natively in T-SQL, no. It does sound like something g you should be doing in your presentation layer anyway.

Comment: Appreciate it Lamu....the problem is that there is no application layer I can use.  We're using SSRS to display this.  That's why I was asking in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to a TVF as a helper function which I use to calcuate elapsed time, perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeDate datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2015-05-28 16:10:27'),
('2018-05-25 22:15:18'),
('2018-06-01 16:52:18'),
(dateadd(SECOND,-3,GetDate())),
(GetDate())


Select A.SomeDate
      ,B.*
      ,TimeAgo = case when years   > 0 then concat(years,' years ago') else 
                 case when months  > 0 then concat(months,' months ago') else
                 case when days    > 0 then concat(days,' days ago') else
                 case when hours   > 0 then concat(hours,' hours ago') else
                 case when minutes > 0 then concat(minutes,' minutes ago') else 
                 case when seconds > 0 then concat(seconds,' seconds ago') else 'just now'
                 end end end end end end
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ( A.SomeDate,GetDate()) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c),
         cteYY(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(YY,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(YY,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteMM(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MM,R,D))  From (Select Top 12 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteYY P Where DateAdd(MM,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,D))  From (Select Top 31 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMM P Where DateAdd(DD,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select [Years]   = cteYY.N
          ,[Months]  = cteMM.N
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          --,[Elapsed] = Format(cteYY.N,'0000')+':'+Format(cteMM.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteDD.N,'00')+' '+Format(cteHH.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteMI.N,'00')+':'+Format(cteSS.N,'00')
     From  cteYY,cteMM,cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS
)
--Max 1000 years
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('1991-09-12 21:00:00.000',GetDate())
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Date-Elapsed] ('2017-01-01 20:30:15','2018-02-05 22:58:35')
```

Comment: If you return `TimeAgo` to the front end. It would be difficult to use and expensive. Try changing `3 seconds ago` to `4 seconds ago` or `2 min 59 sec ago` to `3 min ago` without querying the database again. It would be an extra mess. Isn't it?

Comment: @abdulqayyum That's why I would use something like timeago.js .  I would NEVER update the client with this.

Comment: this will get me started.  I do appreciate it guys.

Comment: @arcee123 Happy to help

Answer (score 3):

Database engines are grounded in set theory, where this kind of work is explicitly out of scope for them.

Database servers are also often expensive to license, where CPU time on the DB is significantly more expensive compared to CPU time in a web server, application server, or desktop.

Database servers are typically difficult to scale outward, such that the database is often a performance bottleneck for a system or application. The more CPU work you can move away from the database, the faster the application can go or the more users it can serve effectively.

---

Put all three of those together, and the common wisdom is this work should be done by the calling application. Let the database just return a `DateTime` value. It's good at that, and can do it while still preserving it's expensive and busy CPU. Let a client language, like C# or Javascript, worry about converting that DateTime value into a string like "Yesterday" or "Tomorrow".

Generally speaking, push the formatting as close to the user/presentation level as possible.